# Laravel Distinct Count

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Any way to make this query work using laravel? DB::raw or Eloquent usage doesn't matter.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT name) FROM tablename;
```

Here's what i've tried but cannot get the proper output:

```
EloquentTableName::select(DB::raw('count(DISTINCT name) as name_count'))->get();
```

This returns something like this and i'd like to fix that:

```
([{"name_count":"15"}])
```

I just want to get count 15.

Comment: can you clarify the difference between current output and expected output?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy i just need to get the int value. I need 15. What i've got is "name_count":"15"

Comment: What if you do `->only("name_count")` instead of `->get()` ?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

you can simply replace get with count in this way:

```
$count = DB::table('tablename')->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT name'));
```

also can do:

```
DB::table('tablename')->distinct('name')->count('name');
```

Answer (score 13):

```php
DB::table('tablename')->distinct()->count('name');
```

is the correct answer.

> <strike>->distinct('name')</strike> *does not* work in Laravel.

Answer (score 7):

You may simply do the following:

```
Tablename::distinct()->count('name');
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do this as smoothly as honey

```
Modal::('yourTable')->distinct()->count('yourAttribute')
```

and it will fetch unique count number of 'yourAttribute'.