# How can count table column unique values in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5

working with laravel 5.6 and mysql. I have following table name as `projects`

```
id  name  type  
1   tuna  bio
2   nhye  IT
3   hyuj  bio
4   tour  IT
5   ghyt  commerce
```

I need count `type` column  values which are unique values. as an example in above table I need count values `3` because there are three different values like bio, IT and commerce. how can I do this?

Comment: please post your old answer here

Comment: actually I need only count unique values. like `3` in above example

Comment: $count = Project::groupBy('type')->count(); dd($count);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Distinct Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868551/laravel-distinct-count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Query builder

```
DB::table('projects')
        ->distinct()
        ->count('type');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this SQL query :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT type) as 'number total' FROM projects
```

The column 'number total' will be the number of differents value in your column 'type'

Comment: I need use this on Laravel controller?

Comment: You have to use it in the file where your execute queries

Answer (score 0):

you can either use 2 ways in order to get the correct answer.

select Count(distinct type) from Projects

OR

select type, count(1) from Projects group by type;

I have used the table name as laravel instead Project

[image]

$data = DB::table("projects")

```
    ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(1) as count_row"))

    ->groupBy(DB::raw("(type)"))

    ->get();
```

print_r($data);