# Laravel - Select Count with no field data repeated

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel-5.8 Eloquent to run a query. I want to get the total trucks utilized by a particular client for all their trips without counting a truck twice. I used the query below, but there is repetition of trucks used more than once:

```
  $truckcount = Trip::where('client_id', $userClientId)
   ->select(\DB::raw("COUNT(truck_no) as count"))
   ->distinct()   
   ->get();
```

How do I write the correct Eloquent query to achieve this?

Comment: [See this answer for eloquent without raw sql.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868746/3585500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 $truckcount = Trip::where('client_id', $userClientId)
   ->select(\DB::raw("COUNT(DISTINCT truck_no) as count"))
   ->get();
```