# count where they don't have the same ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

i need to count all records in my table, but in the **mp_id column** there are repetitions

how to count only once where the content of mp_id is repeated?

so that the count is not wrong, i want the mp_id to count only once and not 3 or 4.

```
  $ingresos = Ingresosmp::All()->count('mp_id');
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please rephrase what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sounds like you first want to get all unique cases of mp_id and count those.
Check the docs for a unique() method to call before count.

Comment: @DanielL I want to count the mp_id only once, but there are several repeated mp_id, I need to filter so that it only counts them once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Distinct Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868551/laravel-distinct-count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ingresos = Ingresosmp::All()->unique('mp_id');
$ingresos = count($ingresos);
```

Verify results with:

```
dd($ingresos);
```

Edit: you can condense this into a single line of code, this is just for readability. You can do this by:

```
$ingresos = count(Ingresosmp::all()->unique('mp_id'));
```

Comment: That's a bad solution since you get all the data from database before looping the result models to generate the unique array then count it. you can directly count from database https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868551/laravel-distinct-count